# Saponification - Oil and Alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, mixtures, fats, soap

I've been reading that a saponification reaction typically involves NaOH or KOH. I was wondering - could anything that contains an OH group cause a saponification reaction? For instance, coconut oil + ethanol? If not, why is a "strong base" needed?

Comment: Not everything what has OH is a strong base, the same as not everything what has H is a strong acid.(Otherwise  table sugar would be both ). Strong base is needed as OH- is needed to react with the ester group. Alkohols do not produce OH-.

Comment: Coconut oil + EtOH might produce transesterification but you will not get any free acids from it.